# After signing the assembly I get: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-assembly

I am working on my first ASP.NET MVC 5 application using Entity Framework 6. The project was created using the Visual Studio 2013 MVC template and uses Internet authentication (with Identity 1.0).

Once I got everything up and running, I wanted to sign my assembly with a strong name and also change the assembly version number. If I do either of these things I get an error:

```
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference...
```

How can I change the assembly version and get EF to sync with the new assembly?

I have looked at several similar issues and they recommend doing a project Clean, empying the Bin folder etc buy none work for me.

I can't see anywhere where my old assembly is referenced, I've checked the Web.config file also.

Any help gratefully accepted!

Comment: are all of your projects signed, did you use same key everywhere?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the fusion logs to get more details. Figure out which 'other' library causes this and follow the chain up to see where you have an old reference.

Comment: I'm just using one assembly that contains the model, controllers and views. The assembly name that is indicated is the main dll assembly.

Comment: Here is the message:(0,0) : error 0004: Can't load the file or assembly 'CalasCovesWeb, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Note that the message is correct, if I have changed the assembly version it would be 1.0.0.1 or if I sign the assembly the PublicKeyToken would not be null. I just need to tell the program to use the updated assembly.

Comment: may you try to delete the key file (.snk) and recreate it? EDIT: i mean, if you are signing with a teste certificate

Comment: Tried this, makes no difference.

Comment: when you did clean the bin folder, did you clean the obj folder either? did you clean the main project bin/obj folder either?

Comment: sign the `CalasCovesWeb` project

Comment: Initally it was unsigned, but its *after* I sign it that the error appears. It seems to be similar to the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725101/purpose-and-semantic-of-imigrationmetadata-interface-in-entity-framework

Comment: Looks like it has been fixed here:https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/1c2ebfeebf7c1835535dfb94749d6c5c7145379e How does one get this update?